# аналоги функции msg_get_queue с php на python

Tags: php, python, linux, веб-программирование

Переношу один проект с php на python. Есть скрипт который создает очередь линукс с определенным ключом заполняет ее данными и отправляет на другую программу работающую с базой данных. Есть ли какие либо аналоги, либо способы реализации данной функции в python?

Сам код для примера

```
$key = 555;     // ключ
// Создаём очередь, в качестве ключа мы должны использовать любое целочисленное значение
$queue = msg_get_queue($key);


/* Соединяемся, выбираем базу данных */
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "judchin", "Qwe321","surgut");

/* проверяем соединение */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$str=   'SELECT
          func.number,
          dop_addr.dop_addr,
          device.address
        FROM func,
             dop_addr
               INNER JOIN device
                 ON dop_addr.id_dev = device.iddevice
        WHERE func.idfunc = '.$idfunc.'
        AND dop_addr.id_dop_addr = '.$id_dop_addr;
        /* Выполняем SQL-запрос*/
$query =mysqli_query($link, $str);

$com_dop_adr_1 = [2, 5, 6, 17];
$com_dop_adr_2 = [12];
$com_dop_adr_3 = [8];
while ($queryres = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    if ( in_array ($queryres['number'],  $com_dop_adr_1)){
        $data_1 = 0;
        $data_0 = 0;
        if ($val > 0){
            $data_0 = (1 << $queryres['dop_addr']);
        }
        else {
            $data_1 = (1 << $queryres['dop_addr']);         // версия 3.3
            //$data_0 = (1 << ($queryres['dop_addr'] + 4)); // версия 3.2
        }
        /*if ($queryres['number'] == 5){
            $queryres['number'] = 6;
        }*/
        $d = '_'.$queryres['address'].'_1_'.$queryres['number'].'_'.$data_1.'_'.$data_0;
        msg_send($queue, 1, $d);
    }
    else if (in_array($queryres['number'],  $com_dop_adr_2) ){
        $val = $val*2;
        $d = '_'.$queryres['address'].'_1_'.$queryres['number'].'_'.$queryres['dop_addr'].'_'.$val;
        msg_send($queue, 1, $d);
        //mysqli_query($link, 'CALL add_to_function('.$queryres['adress'].','.$queryres['dop_addr'].',12,'.$val.');');
        /*$data_1 = $queryres['dop_addr'];
        $data_0 = $val * 2;*/
    }
    else if (in_array($queryres['number'],  $com_dop_adr_3) ){
        
        $d = '_'.$queryres['address'].'_1_'.$queryres['number'].'_'.$queryres['dop_addr'].'_'.$val;
        msg_send($queue, 1, $d);
        
    }
}
/* Закрываем соединение */
mysqli_close($link);
```

Comment: Вероятно вот http://semanchuk.com/philip/sysv_ipc/

Comment: если можно использовать другой примитив, то совет: если при работе с очередью сообщений не используется приоритезация, то она не нужна... используй сокеты...